# Using the lapply() function with many .csv files to compute a new column

Tags: r

I have 60 .csv files, and in each .csv are columns that I would like to use to compute a new column that stores participants accuracy over a number of trials (rows).

'leftright' is a column that tells us whether the correct answer is on the left or right (A is always the correct answer, so it differs from being on the left or right). 'pressed_key' tells us whether participants selected left or right ('Z' for left, 'M' for right).

| leftright | pressed_key |
| --- | --- |
| A_left_B_right | Z |
| A_left_B_right | M |
| B_left_A_right | M |

I have written some code below, but I am getting the following message: 'Error: Argument 2 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector' - I wondered if anyone could help?

```
dat <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0) 
dat <- data.frame(dat)

files <- list.files(path = 'data/', pattern = '*.csv') # load data (60 files)

for (filename in files) {
  
  df = read.csv(filename)
  
  df$correct_key <- lapply(df$leftright, function(x) if (x == 'A_left_B_right') ['Z'] else if (x == 'B_left_A_right') ['M']) # correct answer
  
  df$correct_ans <- (df$correct_key == df$pressed_key)*1 # label whether correct response (1) or incorrect (0)
  
  dat <- bind_rows(dat, df) # bind files

}
```

The desired output is below, where 'correct_key' is the key that *should* have been pressed, and 'correct_ans' denotes whether they chose the correct answer or not (1 = correct, 0 = not correct)

| leftright | pressed_key | correct_key | correct_ans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_left_B_right | Z | Z | 1 |
| A_left_B_right | M | Z | 0 |
| B_left_A_right | M | M | 1 |

Comment: When you write `dat <- bind_rows(dat, df)`, you are calling a variable that does not exist. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that's a good point but in my code I do define 'dat' to begin but forgot to include in the code above!

Comment: Cheers. Testing your script without the actual data is hard... Are you able to identify which line produces the error message at least?

Comment: Line 2 in the loop is where the first error appears, which says "Error: unexpected '[' in:" - so I think this is where the issue might be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the `lapply` statements has incorrect syntax. Try replacing it with this:

```
lapply(df$leftright, function(x) {
  if (x == 'A_left_B_right') {
    'Z'
  } else if (x == 'B_left_A_right') {
    'M'
  }
})
```

Comment: amazing! thank you